# Gridap FEM visualisation of result

Tags: julia

Is there any way to visualise the solution uh in this code

https://gridap.github.io/Tutorials/dev/pages/t001_poisson/ 3

other than writinfg it as vtk file.
plot is not working.

Comment: Hey, perhaps the best way to get a solution would be to post the error you get when trying to plot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.